# Problema ao realizar upload com iPhone em um app Cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, upload, iphone

Olá, estou trabalhando num projeto em que tenho que servir um site externo e responsivo a partir de um app cordova. Está quase tudo funcionando como o esperado, porém estou tendo problemas com o upload de imagens no iPhone.

Como funciona no site: **Após selecionar a imagem ela é convertida para base64 e submetida ao servidor.**

**Problema**: Ao tentar realizar o upload pelo iPhone ele oferece a opção de tirar uma foto no momento. Ao tirar a foto na orientação Portrait essa imagem ao ser submetida fica "deitada", como se ele te obrigasse a tirar a foto na posição Landscape.

Eu gostaria de saber como resolver isso, apenas colocando a imagem na orientação correta, alguém pode me ajudar?

Outra opção seria desabilitar a opção de tirar foto, alguém sabe como remover essa opção?

Se eu permitir que a pessoa apenas selecione nos arquivos isso vai resolver meu problema.

Comment: Está utilizando qual linguagem? Já deu uma olhada aqui? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Comment: Estou utilizando php no backend. Consegui resolver com uma função que verifica a orientação da imagem e corrige, não encontrei solução melhor. Pelo menos funcionou.